# Cyanogenmod installation. Repo sync error. fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/gingerbread

Tags: android, git, github, cyanogenmod, repo

I am following the [official](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Build_for_blade) guide for building cyanogenmod for my device (a1000). 
At first i want to build for any supported device, then port CM for mine, as they recommend.

My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit Laptop

I am stuck on syncing repo step. Everytime i sync it i get this message

```
Fetching projects:  99% (225/227)  fatal: Couldn't find remote ref refs/heads/gingerbread
```

Unexpected end of command stream
error: Cannot fetch CyanogenMod/android_hardware_ti_wpan

error: Exited sync due to fetch errors

I tried:
1."repo sync --force-sync"
2."sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling=0"
3. hardcode dns names of repo in /etc/hosts

none of these solutions worked for me

when i did `repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b cm-12.1` and synced after everything was fine, however, it is wrong repo and according to the guide i use i need to `repo init -u https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android.git -b gingerbread`

Can I build CM using alternative repo init? Can i manually fetch missing project? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed this with commenting project line in .git/manifest.xml

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this _is_ an answer. It's the OP explaining how they solved the issue.